# check if numeric php

Tags: php, html, css

my problem is, i have a form which i fill blabla and after i submit i need to check if the var '$number' contains only 9 numbers. which means that if it contains at least 1 letter or has less or more than 9 length it should return false, else it should return true;

this is what i got so far:

```
if (!is_numeric ($number) { 
//do
} else {
}
```

1st problem: This code should take care of the only numbers part but it doesnt, it always returns false.
2nd: do you guys know of any way to take care of the 9 digits only verification?

thanks and sorry for my bad english, not my native language :P

Comment: yes i did that already it outputs the value i introduced in the textbox so i know the var isnt empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your number may contain unwanted whitespaces which cause the `is_numeric()` test not to work properly
So do the following: `$number = trim($number);` to remove them.

Then indeed this snippet is good to check if your variable is a number:

```
if (!is_numeric ($number)) { 
//do
} else {
}
```

And for the number digits do a `if` statement to see if your number is between `100000000` and `999999999`

**So the full code will be:**

```
$number = trim($number);
if (!is_numeric ($number)) { 
//do
} else {
     if ($number >= 100000000 && $number <= 999999999) {
        // Everything is ok
     } else {

     }
}
```

Comment: Missing `)` on the end of the `if` statement.

Comment: Please explain why you are downvoting me for a missing `)`

Comment: Usually people downvote when code fails, making the answer incorrect.

Comment: Usually people are smart enough to distinguish a wrong code from a typo

Comment: Maybe so, but sometimes people are very fussy around here. My answer was downvoted twice without any explanation, and it was correct all along. Reputation is meaningless here mostly anyway, so I wouldn't worry about it. :)

Comment: Aww yeah didn't see that, that is blamable. Unfortunately I have usued all my votes today, I would have gladly upvoted your answer to reduce this ununderstandable mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understood your complete question coz of you native language :p, but i think you want this:

```
if (is_numeric($number) { 
   if(strlen($number) == 9){
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
} else {
   echo 'Not a number';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if it contains digits and check whether its exactly contains 9.

```php
$number = '123456789';
```

```php
if(!preg_match('/^\d{9}$/', $number)) {
    echo 'not ok';
} else {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

Comment: Why not just `/^\d{9}$/`?

Comment: Syntax Error - You're missing a `}` in front of `else`.